# Reload Form using func viewDidAppear

Tags: swift, viewdidappear

I'm having a problem to perform this action in Swift

```
override func viewDidAppear (animated: Bool) {
    toDoListTable.reloadData ()
}
```

I'm having the following error: Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(LLDB)

how do I solve this problem?

[printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNXyY.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probable cause is that you did not connect your table view with the IBOutlet in your view controller's code.